# Matlab's ode45 not sending initial conditions into function

Tags: matlab, indexing, ode, numerical-integration

I have a quick problem which I hope has a fairly simple solution. I have a function which looks like this:

```
function [dx] = myFunction(x)
```

Where `x` is a column vector with four elements containing the configuration (positions and momenta) of the system. I am trying to use `ode45` to numerically integrate a few particles in this configuration space, like so:

```
[Tout,Yout] = ode45(@(x,t)myFunction(x),[t0 tfinal],x0);
```

Every time I try this I fail, receiving the following error:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions
Error in myFunction (line 9)
x2 = x(2);
```

`ode45` is passing a single element, `x=0`, into `myFunction`, instead of the vector of four elements that `myFunction` is expecting. This is causing the index error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? It would seem that I am not using `ode45` properly.

Comment: How do you initialize the variable `x0`?

Answer (score 0):

ODE integration functions [are of the form *y' = f(t,y)*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#f92-1027216), i.e., they must take time as their first input argument and the state vector as their second (it possible to omit the state vector in the rare cases when the ODE depends only on time). You're not doing this. It's fine that your `myFunction` take only the state vector as input. However, you've defined your anonymous function incorrectly such that it is passing in time as `x` to `myFunction`. Your need to reverse `t` and `x`:

```
[Tout,Yout] = ode45(@(t,x)myFunction(x),[t0 tfinal],x0);
```

Hopefully that will fix everything.

Comment: @JGSuw: Were you able to get your code working? If my answer was help, please accept it. Thank you.